# ASP.NET Gridview control how to display query data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I have a problem about Gridview control show values; I want to sum duplicated values from three columns from one table and then put the final result to Fridview cells. But the data can't be shown on the Gridview, however I test the sql command in my sql management studio It works well, anyone can help me to solve it? Thanks!

My table name is **[Assessment]**; 
the all columns are:**[assessmentID],[workstation],[Date].....[numberOfhigh],[numberOffurther],[numberOflow].** 

 
 Now I use " **SELECT SUM(numberOfhigh),SUM(numberOffurther),SUM(numberOflow) FROM Assessment GROUP BY workstation HAVING COUNT(*) > 1** " in order to get duplicated workstations total risk.

front end code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" style="margin-left: 318px" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="269px" Width="440px" >
        <Columns>

           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="High Risk"  DataField="high">           
            <ItemStyle BackColor="Red" />             
            </asp:BoundField>

             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Further Risk" DataField="further">             
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />            
            </asp:BoundField>

              <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Low Risk" DataField="low">              
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#33CC33" />            
            </asp:BoundField>

        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Back end code:

```
  if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex == 2 && DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {

                sqlConn.Open();

                string cmdText = "SELECT SUM(numberOfhigh),SUM(numberOffurther),SUM(numberOflow) FROM Assessment GROUP BY workstation HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdText, sqlConn);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                sda.Fill(ds);
                GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                GridView1.DataBind();


                sqlConn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: I guess you are missing column Aliases in your query

Comment: How to write it, can you write an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need aliases in your `SELECT`, or else the `GridView` won't know what to bind to.

```
SELECT SUM(numberOfhigh) AS high, SUM(numberOffurther) AS further, SUM(numberOflow) AS low
FROM Assessment
GROUP BY workstation HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

use the column name exactly what you have used as the field name in your database for example

```
       <asp:BoundField HeaderText="High Risk"  DataField="numberOfhigh">           
        <ItemStyle BackColor="Red" />             
        </asp:BoundField>

         <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Further Risk" DataField="numberOffurther">             
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />            
        </asp:BoundField>

          <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Low Risk" DataField="numberOflow">              
        <ItemStyle BackColor="#33CC33" />            
        </asp:BoundField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

use the above code for front end